# Improving ExpansionPanelList performance for big item count in flutter?

Tags: flutter, performance

ExpansionPanelList seems not to have a on demand builder method for flutter to call when new items need to be created. This leads to the creation of all items in the ExpansionPanelList everytime it needs to be rebuilt.

In my particular scenario, I can have around 10k items and it turns pretty slow.

This is how I am building and filling the ExpansionPanelList:

```
List<ExpansionPanel> widgets = state.games.map<ExpansionPanel>((VMUserGame game) {
  var gameAddedStatus = VMGameTools.getGameStatus(game);

  return ExpansionPanel(
    canTapOnHeader: true,
    headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: Text(game.userGame.name, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5, textAlign: TextAlign.left)),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 24, 0),
                  child: game.userGame.isExternal ? null : Text(StringTools.bytesToStorageUnity(game.userGame.gameSize)),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 24, 0),
                  child: _getExeCurrentStateIcon(gameAddedStatus),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _nsgpBloc.renameGame(context, game);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  tooltip: tr("rename_game"),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _nsgpBloc.deleteGame(context, game);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                  tooltip: tr("delete"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            if(game.foldingState) Text("${game.userGame.path}",textAlign: TextAlign.left, style: TextStyle(color:themeExtension.gameCardHeaderPath, fontSize: 13),)
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
    body: _buildGameTile(context, themeExtension,  game.userGame, state.availableProntonNames),
    isExpanded: game.foldingState,
  );
}).toList();

return Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        _nsgpBloc.swapExpansionStateForItem(index);
      },
      children: widgets,),
);
```